# SolrCloud on Azure PaaS

Tags: solr, azure, paas

I am setting up a Sitecore 9.2 Production instance and ideally would like to Setup SolrCloud in Azure PaaS Web Apps.

In test environments i have setup Solr on a single PaaS App Service and it is working perfectly well, but being a single instance it is not fault tolerant, so in production i would like to move to SolrCloud with with Multiple Nodes each running in a separate App Service.

There are some good articles on here about setting up Solr on PaaS (like this [one](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9414/)) and a few articles that talk about SolrCloud setup with SaaS provides like SearchStax (eg [this](https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2019/01/07/you-can-have-solr-as-a-service-now/)).

But i can't find anyone talking about setting up SolrCloud in Azure PaaS, or even suggesting this, which makes me think its either 

1. Not possible. 

2. Not desirable (aka very complicated)

3. Perfectly possible, just nobody has been there yet or documented their experiences. 

4. Its be done and documented, but i am not looking in the right places :)

I would appreciate anyone's thoughts on this.

Comment: It's number 2 in your list. In my opinion, searchstax is the way to go. I will not entertain any other way to do solr setup.

Comment: @VincentLui Have you tried setting up SolrCloud on PaaS yourself? If so i am curious what makes it more complicated than setting up SolrCloud on a VM?

Comment: Seconding SearchStax, no question.

Comment: +1 for SearchStax. Also, 9.2 has a few known issues with solrcloud with more than 1 instance - if you read the 9.3 release notes you can find them. I'm running 9.2 with a single searchstax instance in prod with no issues and no downtime in the last 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

Azure PaaS (Web Apps) cannot support production SolrCloud environments because the ZooKeeper ensemble requires ports to be open other than 80/443.